# Trying to retrieve all username from database in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am learning laravel 5. I want to list all the username on my page from database.

Here is the controller i am using :

```
namespace Horsefly\Http\Controllers;
use profile;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Horsefly\User;
use Horsefly\Http\Requests;     
use Horsefly\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProfileController extends Controller
 {
  public function profiledetails()
{


    return view('profiledetails')
    ->with('auth::user',auth::user()->get());
}
```

Here is my view :

```
   <ul>
   @foreach($users as $user)
    <li>

  {{$user->name()}}
   </li>
   @endforeach
   </ul>
Here is my model



   <?php
   namespace Horsefly;
   use DB;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class profile extends Model
    {
      $users = DB::table('users')->get();
     }
```

I will be great if someone helps me out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update controller,

```
 class ProfileController extends Controller
     {
      public function profiledetails()
    {

        $users = DB::table('users')->get();
        return view('profiledetails')
        ->with('users',compact($data));
    }
```

View

```
<ul>
   @foreach($users as $user)
    <li>

  {{$user->username}}
   </li>
   @endforeach
   </ul>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. It is showing error..... ErrorException in ProfileController.php line 64: Undefined variable: data in with('users',compact($data));